# MySQL ORDER BY one column and a second column

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is different but I have read this similar SO post:
[How can I order by two columns, if result is equal, consider another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814895/how-can-i-order-by-two-columns-if-result-is-equal-consider-another-column)

I am interested in 2 columns:

- production_id
- date

The query is:

```
SELECT BATCH_ISSUED.production_id, MANUFACTURE_DATE.date
FROM BATCH_ISSUED LEFT JOIN
     MANUFACTURE_DATE
     ON BATCH_ISSUED.production_id = MANUFACTURE_DATE.production_id
WHERE MANUFACTURE_DATE.active='1'
ORDER BY MANUFACTURE_DATE.date ASC,BATCH_ISSUED.production_id ASC
```

This fetches the data and sorts it by date (old > new) and then sorts by `id` but it needs to group all of the same `id` together which may mean GROUP BY needs to be included somehow.

An example of the data:

```
195 2017-10-10
196 2017-10-10
196 2017-10-10
258 2017-10-10
258 2017-10-10
189 2017-10-12
190 2017-10-12
258 2017-10-12
212 2017-10-13
213 2017-10-13
```

It should be presented like this, for example with the ID 258 kept together in date order:

```
    195 2017-10-10
    196 2017-10-10
    196 2017-10-10

    258 2017-10-10
    258 2017-10-10
    258 2017-10-12

    189 2017-10-12
    190 2017-10-12
    212 2017-10-13
    213 2017-10-13
```

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: What's your sql query like? Whats the sample data? Whats the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `WHERE` clause turns the `OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.  As a result, the `JOIN` is not even needed.  So your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT md.production_id, md.date
FROM MANUFACTURE_DATE md
WHERE md.active = 1
ORDER BY md.date ASC, md.production_id ASC;
```

Then you can use a `JOIN` to get the information you want:

```
SELECT md.production_id, md.date
FROM MANUFACTURE_DATE md JOIN
     (SELECT md2.production_id, MIN(md2.date) as mind
      FROM MANUFACTURE_DATE md2
      WHERE md.active = 1
      GROUP BY md2.production_id
     ) mmd
     ON md.production_id = md2.production_id
WHERE md.active = 1
ORDER BY mdd.mind ASC, md.production_id ASC, md.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's enought to invert your order by sequence:

```
 ORDER BY BATCH_ISSUED.production_id DESC, MANUFACTURE_DATE.date ASC,
```

Comment: Sorry @Emily Scarpetta but I find your solution only half solves my issue.

Continuing with the example data from my question So yes your code keeps the ID 258 is kept together but the date order for other ID is not sorted oldest > newest. Thanks for your suggestion I gave you a positive vote